# Can we use 通る about 心地 or 気持ち?

Tags: grammar

Just before these sentence main character told that he is worried about crossing the tunnel(because of some childhood memories). That is why I'm not sure what is he talking about in this sentence(bold one). About crossing the tunnel「通ってしまえば」 and it wasn't scary at all「どうということもなかった」, or he talking about 「心地」 from the sentence before ?

> トンネルの出口の光が見える。それは瞬く間に、トンネルの闇を払い、僕のーー俺の意識を現実へと引き戻してくれた。電車がトンネルから抜け出すーー先頭から車内に陽の光が一気に差し込まれていく。それは視界の一瞬の変化でしかない。しかしトンネルの圧迫感が体に残っていて、体感的に徐々に変わっていくような心地だった。**身構えてしまったが、通ってしまえば、どうということもなかった。**

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

通ってしまえば refers to トンネル. 心地 as a noun doesn't couple with 通る.